# WPF TextBox Background binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing TextBox binding as shown below. But the background color doesn't change. Any help is appreciated!

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextbox" Text="Test" Background="{Binding Path=FirstNameBackground,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

C# code:

```
public SolidColorBrush FirstNameBackground
{
    get
    {
        return firstNameBackground;
    }
    set
    {
        firstNameBackground = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstNameBackground");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are following MVVM, don't use x:Name.   How does your OnPropertyChanged implementation look?

Comment: x:Name works just fine in mvvm.

Comment: Are you seeing any binding errors in the output window of Visual Studio (they usually show up in red)?

Comment: When are you creating your firstNameBackground first value? are you using the VM constructor?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.

A). Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, without it binding to the xaml will only work one way and then stop, since there is no way to notify when property has changed.

B). Your xaml is not properly built. You must have a closing bracket at the end of textbox such as

```
<textbox/>
or
<textbox></textbox>
```

C). How is your datacontext set? If it is not set to anything , this will not work. This can be done by
  a. `datacontext =this` in your codebehind
  b. settings datacontext in xaml using `window.datacontext` as the xaml key

D). The information given is very very vague and i can only make decisions and suggestions based on common mistakes I have seen when building xaml/wpf apps. Please provide more information on
  1. How datacontext is set.
  2. How full xaml looks like
  3. full codebeind/viewmodel if applicable

Comment: `<textbox/>` isn't strictly needed, as long as the tag is closed someplace the posted code may be valid.  There may be attached properties or other objects the OP didn't include.